# TFS Upgrade 2013 to 2015

Tags: tfs

I had started the upgrade from 2012 to TFS 2015 3 days before 2 of the collections have completed and one of the collection out of 3 is running from Day one.Its size is about 2.5 TB.Having said that , i had performed same upgrade months back and it had finished successfully in 52 hours.Can any one help on the reason why it is taking a longer time now ?

Look at the screen shot for reference:
[Upgrade Window in progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lv0ZL.png)

Comment: Is your hardware exactly the same? Has the database grown? Are there many test attachments or other things that increase database size? Have you used the TfsPreUpgrade tool? (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/TFS/upgrade/pre-upgrade)

Comment: 2.5TB is a lot of data...

Answer (score 1):

There is a log named **TFS_TFSUpgrade_Date_Time** with the type *TFS Upgrade* in Team Foundation Server Administration Console→ Logs.

You can compare the logs between twice upgrade to check which step had taken a longer time.